# I'm doing this code and I am receiving an UnboundLocalError: local variable 'points' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have my code for an assignment. Unfortunately I am getting an Unbound Local Error -  :

```py
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'points' referenced before assignment.
```

Can you help me solve this problem, so I am able to understand?

```
def do_calc(x, y):
    grade_1 = {"a": 4, "b": 3, "c": 2, "d": 1, "f": 0}
    points = 0
    count = 0
    while count < y:
        for i in range(y):
            letterGrade = raw_input("Enter letter grade: ")
            points += grade_1[letterGrade.lower()]
            count +=1   
        return x, y

def main():
    x, y = do_calc(x, y)
    Grade_point_average = x/y
main()
```

Comment: You're passing points into the do_calculation() method before its declared. It looks like you can just remove it from the method definition altogether. It doesn't seem to be needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you think that `points` has to be passed into `do_calculation` when in fact it is just returned:

```py
def do_calculation(number):
    grades = {"a": 4, "b": 3, "c": 2, "d": 1, "f": 0}
    points = 0
    count = 0
    while count < number:
        for i in range(number):
            letterGrade = input("Enter letter grade: ")
            points += grades[letterGrade.lower()]
            count +=1
            print(points)    
        return points

def main():
    name = input("Enter your name:")
    grade_title = input("Enter your grade      level[Ex.Freshman,Sophmore,Junior,Senior]:")
    number = int(input("Enter number of courses: "))
    points = do_calculation(number)
    GPA = points/number
    print("Grade level:", grade_title)
    print("Hello", name, "Your GPA is", GPA)
main()
```

In fact, the `number` parameter *should* be passed in and *not* returned.

So your function *takes* `number` and returns `points`.

Comment: `return points` may be outside of the while block?

Comment: @arsho: Well, no, it is the `while` block which is redundant. Anyway, we'll have to wait for that "problem" to show up. For now it is hidden by the `UnboundLocalError`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you need to pass "points" into do_calculation. (Also it looks like your indentation might be incorrect at the end of the method.)

```
def do_calculation(number):
    grades = {"a": 4, "b": 3, "c": 2, "d": 1, "f": 0}
    points = 0
    count = 0
    while count < number:
        for i in range(number):
            letterGrade = input("Enter letter grade: ")
            points += grades[letterGrade.lower()]
            count +=1
    print(points)    
    return points
```